# REMOTE_USER missing in %ENV for Perl script on Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to migrate a site from a super ancient server (6 or 7 years old!), and it uses `AuthFormProvider file` to log the user in. This seems to work, apart from the fact it doesn't pass along REMOTE_USER into %ENV{} in my Perl script. The trimmed down  is:

```
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:8443>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/mysite/web/example.com/public_html
    Alias /vstats/ /home/mysite/web/example.com/stats/
    Alias /error/ /home/mysite/web/example.com/document_errors/
    #SuexecUserGroup mysite mysite
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/example.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/example.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/example.com.error.log
    <Directory /home/mysite/web/example.com/stats>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/mysite/web/example.com/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        SSLRequireSSL

        Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/mysite/web/example.com/public_html/private/>
        AuthFormProvider file
        AuthUserFile "/home/mysite/web/example.com/public_html/cgi-bin/public/dbusers.db"
        AuthType form
        AuthName "Password Required"
        AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://www.example.com/loginerror.shtml"
        AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation "http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/private/db.cgi"
        AuthFormLogoutLocation "https://www.example.com/loggedout.html"
        ErrorDocument 401 "/loginerror.shtml"
        Session On
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        Require valid-user

    </Directory>


    <Location "/dologin.html">
        SetHandler form-login-handler
        AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation "http://www.example.com/private/index.html"
        AuthFormLogoutLocation "http://www.example.com/loggedout.html"
        ErrorDocument 401 "/loginerror.shtml"
        AuthFormProvider file
        AuthUserFile "/home/mysite/web/example.com/public_html/cgi-bin/public/dbusers.db"
        AuthType form
        AuthName "Password Required"
        Session On
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
    <Location "/dologout.html">
        SetHandler form-logout-handler
        AuthType form
        AuthName "Password Required"
        AuthUserFile "/home/mysite/web/example.com/public_html/public/dbusers.db"
        AuthFormLogoutLocation "http://www.example.com/loggedout.html"
        ErrorDocument 401 "/loginerror.shtml"
        Session On
        SessionMaxAge 1
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        Require valid-user
    </Location>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm-example.com.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0

    IncludeOptional /home/mysite/conf/web/example.com/apache2.ssl.conf_*
    IncludeOptional /etc/apache2/conf.d/*.inc
</VirtualHost>
```

Module wise, I have these enabled:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_form_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authnz_fcgi_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 perl_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 remoteip_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 request_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 rpaf_module (shared)
 ruid2_module (shared)
 session_module (shared)
 session_cookie_module (shared)
 session_crypto_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It is not clear from which location your Perl script is called. I can see `AddHandler cgi-script` in `public_html` only and this section doesn't require authorization, so it won't get `REMOTE_USER` defined.

Comment: @AlexD OMG.. you legend! Man I feel stupid now. It was missing /cgi-bin from the /private <Location> ... DUH! Works fine now :) There really does get a point in the day when you should just stop working!